# show that the function is analytic at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin z}{z}&z \neq 0\\1&z=0\end{cases} $$

(a).Using the maclaurin expansion for $\sin z$, show that for all $z$,

$f(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\dots$

Attempt:

How would I go about showing this? Could I just claim that this function agrees with dividing the series $\sin z$ by $z$ and adding the fact that $f(0)=1$ corrects for the removable discontinuity which is present at $z=0$ for $\frac{\sin z}{z}$?

I do not know how to go about showing this. Also why would $f$ be analytic at the origin, is it because we have a taylor series representation for the function there?

Answer (score 1):

Just write down the expansion of $\sin z$ and divide by $z$ when $z \neq 0$. For $z=0$ verify the equation directly. Analyticity of $f$ follows from the fact that it has a convergent power series expansion.

(For (a) there is no need to prove analyticity of $f$).

Comment: To verify the equation directly do I just show at $z=0$,$1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\dots=1$?

Comment: Yes, that is it! @user764658

Answer (score 0):

There's not a whole lot to show. Assuming you know that the definition of an analytic function is it has a convergent power series, you can produce the power series that you did. Just show it converges using, say, the ratio test.